# Complex delayed unpublishing

Tags: rules, nodes

I want a node that the user can edit the published setting on. (Via publish_content)

It should be unpublished by default 4 months after being published, but paused not reset when unpublished.

Also, there should be a cck field allowing the user to alter the time published beforehand but this should not be editable if the content has already been published and is in delay (Or unpublished and paused).

I've been looking at rules since this seems to be a pretty complex task, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it and I'm new to rules.

After the initial (4 month) delay is over the user should be allowed to start this whole thing again.

Comment: When you say "but paused not reset when unpublished" I assume you mean that the published flag just changes to not published?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the rules scheduler module (part of the [rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)). You should be able to do most of the things with date calculation and rules scheduler.

If you're missing something in rules you might have to implement your own rules action. Have a look at [hook_rules_action_info()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7).

Comment: After working it out on paper I know what I need to do.

Comment: If the node is being published (`Node unedited unpublished AND node published`) schedule unpublishing for the `"Time remaining" field + now`. If the node is being unpublished, somehow find `scheduled unpublish date - now` and save it in that previous field *as well as* somehow disable the field from editing. I don't know how to find the sheduled unpublish date or how to disable the field from editing reliably. One way to do it would be to have the field's visibility dependant on the value of a hidden field but idk how to do that